# Can't compare strings using Coq standard library

Tags: coq

I want to compare strings using eqb which is in standard librarny Coq.Strings.String,
but following code dosen't work.

```
Require Import String.

Check eqb "foo" "bar".
(*
The reference eqb was not found in the current environment.
Query commands should not be inserted in scripts
*)
```

Am I using it incorrectly, or am I failing to build the environment?

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.5
BuildVersion:   19F101
$ ocaml --version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.04.2
$ opam --version
2.0.7
$ coqc --version
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.7.0 (June 2020)
compiled on Jun 28 2020 18:21:00 with OCaml 4.04.2
```

Comment: I can plug that right into `coqide` or even `coqtop` and it works fine. That Coq version does look ancient (2+ years!), though... Maybe that's it.

Answer (score 3):

`String.eqb` is a fairly recent addition.

Here's the docs for the 8.7 version of the stdlib, where you can see that there is no `eqb`: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.7.2/stdlib/Coq.Strings.String.html

(You can find other versions at https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/)

The solution is to upgrade Coq or define `eqb` manually.

Comment: [`eqb` appears to appear in v8.9.0.](https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/a697b20f5013abb834cd9dca3fdef2bee53221ad)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!  
I noticed now that the blog I was referring to when I installed is written 2 years before :(

Comment: We’re now at Coq 8.11.2, and 8.12 should arrive soon!